# How do I prevent $\mathcal{MathJax}$ from putting excessive amounts of space around quotation marks?

Tags: support, mathjax, typesetting

### How do I prevent $\mathcal{MathJax}$ from putting excessive amounts of space around quotation marks?

$\mathtt{"Hello" + "World"}$ denotes the string $\mathtt{"Hello World"}$.

Let $A = \begin{Bmatrix}\mathtt{"Apple"} , \mathtt{"Orange"}, \mathtt{"Kiwi"}\end{Bmatrix}$.

#### The Source Code is Shown Below

```
$\mathtt{"Hello" + "World"}$ denotes the string $\mathtt{"Hello World"}$.  

Let $A = \begin{Bmatrix}\mathtt{"Apple"} , \mathtt{"Orange"}, \mathtt{"Kiwi"}\end{Bmatrix}$.
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127574  Essentially, you are asking `\mathtt` do do something it isn't meant to do.  Better to use `\texttt` (e.g. `$\left\{ \texttt{"hello"}, \texttt{"world"} \right\}$` renders as $\left\{ \texttt{"hello"}, \texttt{"world"} \right\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hack would be $A=\{“\mathtt{abcde}”,“\mathtt{12345}”,“\mathtt{!?$@*}”\}$ where I used the Unicode characters `“ ”` for the quotations.

Comment: Your solution made me laugh. I have had problem for many years trying to compile code which contained left double quotes or right double quotes. Most compilers require ASCII straight double quotes. You have to write `print("hello world")` instead of `“print()”`. However, in $\mathcal{MathJax}$ the quotation marks `“ ”` are useful. In, $\LaTeX$ left-double back-tick gives you a left-quote, but back-ticks are stack exchange mark-up language for **BEGIN MONOSPACED TELETYPE CODE BLOCK**